# ArrayList find field as per pojo object

Tags: java, android, sorting

hi i have model of `ArrayList<D>` in that i have to find value as per pirority . 
 say i have model which hold

```
public class model{
 String name,status;  }
```

and this list holds value 
say position 1 - status "D"
say position 2 - status "f"
say position 3 - status "a"
some on

now i want it should 1 st search for value D then A then F .. i am doing it by

```
  for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
 //for D
return i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
//for A
 return i;
  }

for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
//for F
 return i;
  }
```

any good way to find

Comment: Are you trying to "search" the list for an instance with specific position value or "sort" the list based on the position value (in the order of D, F, A) or search in the order of D, F, A?

Comment: ```if (d.get(i).status.equals("D")) return i;``` ?

Comment: @saka ya each loop have  if (d.get(i).status.equals("D"))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method provided by the ArrayList itself:

> public int indexOf(Object o)
>
> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

However, for this to work you would need to make a minor arrangement to your `D` class, wherein two instances of this class are equal if they have the same `status` value. Thus, you would need to *override* the `equals` method.

```
public class D {
 String name;
 String status;  

 ...
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if(obj instanceof D)
          return ((D)obj).getStatus().equals(this.getStatus());
      return false;
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<D> myList = ...;
//Search for an item which has a status of 'D'
D searchKey = new D();
d.setStatus("D");

//This will go through the entire array list and gets the location of the first element which satisfies D's equals method.
int index = myList.indexOf(searchKey);
```

Comment: what ?          didn't got you

Comment: @bob: See my update, hopefully it helps. If not, please specify what you did not understand.

Comment: @npinti How do you find by name?

Comment: @saka1029: In this example you cannot. You could either have a `for` loop which goes through all the items and checks the properties specifically, or else, in this case, you could make the `equals` method smarter where if you pass an *empty* status (for `obj`) it will search by `name`.

Comment: @npinti it always gives 0

Comment: @bob: please update your question with your new code